# Integer to String Convertion in XSLT

Tags: string, xslt, wso2, integer, wso2-esb

In my WSO2 ESB project , I am using xslt files for transformation. I need to manage the type of the values from the endpoint. My payload is JSON and legacy systems's payload is also JSON. I am trying to change the integer value to string value.

Tried to use script in sequence taking payload and using js but I need to manage it in xslt.

For example ;

`<xsl:if test="//jsonObject/searchTerm">
   <searchTerm><xsl:value-of select="//jsonObject/searchTerm"/></searchTerm>
</xsl:if>`

searchTerm value is an integer value from the endpoint but i need to transfer it as string to other system.
Could you please advise about this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you try this,

```
 <xsl:if test="//jsonObject/searchTerm">
   <searchTerm>@@@<xsl:value-of select="//jsonObject/searchTerm"/></searchTerm>
 </xsl:if>
```

Comment: Hello BK, I tried the solution but WSO2 is giving an error about transformation, is there any  additional conf or smt for making it work?

Comment: You need to add some conf to `/synapse.properties`

Comment: Could you add these to ESB_HOME\conf\synapse.properties `synapse.commons.json.json.output.disableAutoPrimitive.customReplaceRegex=@@@

synapse.commons.json.output.xmloutMultiplePI=true`

Answer (score -1):

Check this code:

```
<xsl:if test="//jsonObject/searchTerm">
   <searchTerm><xsl:value-of select="string(//jsonObject/searchTerm)"/></searchTerm>
</xsl:if>
```